# Sequence of real random variables.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, statistics

Let $X_{n}$ be a sequence of real random variables over a probabilistic space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$, $\{x_{n}\}_{n}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $x_{n}\searrow_{n} x$ and such that $\mathbb{P}(X_{n}\leq x_{n})\geq 1/2$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I want to prove that
$$\limsup_{n}\mathbb{P}(X_{n}\leq x)\geq \cfrac{1}{2} - \epsilon$$

for an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$.

We have that, for all $\delta > 0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_{n} - x \leq \delta$ for all $n\geq N$. Thus, for this delta, we have that

$$\limsup_{n}\mathbb{P}(X_{n} \leq x)\geq\limsup_{n}\mathbb{P}(X_{n} \leq x_{n} - \delta)$$

In this point i don't know how to proof that. It seems to be easy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\ x_n>x\ $, for all $\ n\ $ and $\ X_n=\frac{x+x_n}{2}\ $ with probability $1$.  That is, the distribution of $\ X_n\ $ has a single atom of weight $1$ at $\ X_n=\frac{x+x_n}{2}\ $. Then $\ \mathbb{P}\big(X_n\le x_n\big)=1\ge\frac{1}{2}\ $ for all $\ n\in\mathbb{N}\ $, but $\ \mathbb{P}\big(X_n\le x\big)=0\ $ for all $\ n\in\mathbb{N}\ $, so $\ \limsup_\limits{n}\,\mathbb{P}\big(X_n\le x\big)=\lim_\limits{n} \mathbb{P}\big(X_n\le x\big)=0\ $.